# How do I install self-updating 32- and 64-bit Java?

Tags: java, security

When I go to http://java.com, it offers an easy button to install Java. It doesn't tell me which version, it just figures it out automatically. It adds an icon in Control Panel named "Java (32-bit).

[image]

If I open that, there's an Update tab. I like that, because Java is a known target for hackers, so I want to keep it up to date as much as possible.

[image: Java update tab]

I also want 64-bit Java. If I go to http://java.com, there's a link to [See all Java downloads](http://java.com/en/download/manual.jsp). 64-bit Java is listed there, but it gives me "Offline" installer, which doesn't include automatic updating.

How can I get my 64-bit Java to check for updates automatically?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While researching the question, I found the answer:

http://www.java.com/en/download/faq/java_win64bit.xml

> Users should download 64-bit Java software, if they are running 64-bit browsers. For downloading 64-bit Java click 64-bit manual download
>
> **Note: At this time, Online Installation and Java Update features are not available for 64-bit architectures. This means that you will not see an Update tab as part of the Java Control Panel. You can manually update Java on 64-bit Windows by running the latest Java 64-bit offline installer**

Comment: It's staggering that Oracle still haven't addressed this issue, despite the fact that 64-bit users must represent a sizeable proportion of their user base. Madness.

Comment: Since Java 8 Update 20 the update feature is also available for 64-bit architectures. I checked it with Update 25 on my machine.

Answer (score 0):

I think we need to have answered whether it is required to uninstall the previous 64Bit Java version and install the new Java 64Bit seperately. I mean if that is the case then running the offline installer for the new version is hardly and "update" but rather an uninstall of the old version and a fresh install of the new version. But is this really required?

As a note, Oracles own install instruction for Java 64Bit does not give any information about whether to uninstall the old version(see below). Not uninstalling an old Java version is dangerous since insecure parts of the old version could be able to be exploited as long as that old version is not removed, even when the new version is installed.

If anyone know the full step by step procedure to successfully and securely install new versions of Java 64Bit it would be really great to know.

(taken from http://www.java.com/en/download/faq/java_win64bit.xml)
Follow these instructions for installing 64-bit Java on your system:

1. Choose the 64-bit Windows offline download. The File Download dialog box appears.
2. Choose the folder location. (Save the file to a known location on your computer, for example, to your desktop) and Click Save.
3. Close all applications including the browser.
4. Double-click on the saved file icon to start the installation process

Comment: I think you're asking a question, not answering one.

Comment: okay.. I just thought the information was very relevant to the issue being asked.